# Read dictionary key value in ansible using pattern/wildcard match

Tags: dictionary, variables, ansible, wildcard

My variable file obtained is as below:

cat myvar.yml

```
dbname: ser1
url_ser1: url1
url_ser2: url2
dbname: ser2
my_ser1_port: 12207
my_ser2_port: 23332
```

To start off in the first debug, I wish to display the two key (could be more than 2 keys as well) values for `dbname` viz `ser1` & `ser2`

I then wish to use the first key's value i.e `ser1` to pull all values whose key contains `ser1` i.e `url1` and `12207`

Then `ser2` value to get `url2` and `23332`

Thus, i need the output as below:

```
The dbname are ser1 & ser2
dbname `ser1` URL is url1 and port is 12207
dbname `ser2` URL is url2 and port is 23332
```

Below is my playbook  however, i got no clue how to read such variable:

```
---
  - name: ReadJsonfile
    hosts: localhost
    tasks:
      - include_vars: myvar.yml
      - debug:
          msg: "{{ dbname }}"
```

The above prints only the second dbname value i.e `ser2` and not both which is what i require.

```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ '*'+item+'*' }}"
    loop: "{{ dbname }}"
```

The above fails with error.

Can you please suggest how can i get the desired values of variable's from yaml.

Comment: dbname is simple variable, so it takes the last value of your myvar.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to write your myvar.yml like this:

```
dbname: ['ser1', 'ser2']
url_ser1: url1
url_ser2: url2
my_ser1_port: 12207
my_ser2_port: 23332
```

so you could loop over dbname...

```
- name: Reproduce issue
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
         
  tasks:
    - include_vars: variables.yml
    - debug: 
        msg: "dbname {{ item }} URL is {{ url }} and port is {{ port }}"
      loop: "{{ dbname }}"
      vars:
        port: "{{ lookup('vars', 'my_' + item + '_port' ) }}"
        url: "{{ lookup('vars', 'url_' + item) }}"
      when: hostvars[ansible_host]['my_' + item + '_port'] is defined and 
            hostvars[ansible_host]['url_' + item] is defined
```

so `lookup('vars', 'my_' + item + '_port' )` = `hostvars[ansible_host]['my_' + item + '_port']`

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=ser1) => {
    "msg": "dbname ser1 URL is url1 and port is 12207"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=ser2) => {
    "msg": "dbname ser2 URL is url2 and port is 23332"
}
```

Comment: In realtime the variable file will be constructed on the fly. So it may have any of the variable missing say `url_ser2` which will not be know to the play. How do we address such issues ... if you could update the answer with a when variable is defined / present condition ?

Comment: add condition on hostvars.ansible_host, all vars are declred inside it..

Comment: i suggest you to debug hostvars[ansible_host]